# How can I make the Botscout feature work in the EasyCalcCheck+ security plugin?

Tags: plugin, security

I'm using EasyCalcCheck+ to beef up security on a Joomla site. In general it works well, adding a random math question to contact forms and registration.

ECC+ also has options that enable integration with Akismet, StopForumSpam, Project Honeypot, and Botscout. I've been able to get all of these working, except Botscout. When I enable the Botscout check (suing my Botscout API key), the check always fails ("You failed the spam check. Please try again!").

Has anyone out there been able to make this work? ECC+ has a support forum, but I didn't find anything useful there, and a paid subscription is required to post. I've also searched for an ECC+ log, with no success.